# Teamcity. Как добавить ссылку на сборку из зависимости (dependencies)?

Tags: teamcity

есть сборка, в ней есть build step котором работает скрипт, он тянет артефакты из другой сборки(проекта), которая указывается в dependencies, и подкладывает в нужное место на сервер. Есть так же уведомления, в которых говорится из какой сборки были артефакты, как сделать так чтобы можно было добавить ссылка на сборку из dependencies в уведомления? В dependencies можно подставлять разные сборки

Comment: стандартное штатное уведомление?

Answer (score 0):

у вас доступны параметры зависимового проекта

```
%dep.Test_BuildParent.system.teamcity.buildType.id%
%dep.Test_BuildParent.build.number%
```

вы знаете адрес вашего сервера. вы можете склеить путь самосостоятельно в параметрах child проекта и предать переменную, которая будет содержать ссылку на зависимость

```
http://localhost:8111/viewLog.html?buildId=%dep.Test_BuildParent.build.number%&buildTypeId=%dep.Test_BuildParent.system.teamcity.buildType.id%&tab=buildResultsDiv
```

Comment: Это точно про уведомления?

Comment: пока писал тебе ответ, начал сомневаться в том, что именно хочет ТС